# How to make map areas visible with Firefox devtools?

Tags: firefox, area, firefox-developer-tools

If you hover over an area, devtools does not highlight the area:

[image]

Is there any setting to get this feature back?

I know, there are free tools, plugins and stuff, but it was quite handy editing map areas within Firebug / Firefox devtools.

Comment: [Firebug is no longer supported. Stop using it.](https://getfirebug.com)

Comment: Oh my! Force of habit! I Of course I mean the Firefox's devtools... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible yet. There's an [enhancement request filed for implementing this feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1047812), though.